# Why do some random-seeming questions have huge numbers of views?

Tags: discussion

I am sometimes surprised at certain questions that have received huge numbers of views. For example, I just stumbled across [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60119/kinetic-energy-of-alpha-particle-in-212po-decay). I mean it no disrespect - it's a perfectly nice question - but it only has three votes and is quite esoteric and closed as homework-like. I can't imagine that people often search for keywords that lead to this question, or click on it based on its title. Nevertheless, it has almost 17,000 views, which almost puts it within the highest percentile of the most widely-viewed questions on the entire community.

Could this be the result of bots or a bug in the analytics? Or is there something about questions like this that I'm missing which makes them immensely popular? (Again, I mean no disrespect to the OP and I don't mean to be snarky - I'm genuinely curious.)

Comment: *" it has almost 17,000 views, which I believe puts it well within the highest percentile of the most widely-viewed questions on the entire network."* Not even close. That's pretty active for Physics.SE, but the really high activity sites generate multiple 10,000 view questions per day. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question for evidence.

Comment: @dmckee Sorry, I edited to say entire "community", not "network". I was basing that on the fact that only 2490 out of 123839 physics questions have the "Famous Question" badge, and 17000 is significantly past the threshold, so assuming a rapid falloff in the distribution, this question's view count should be above the median Famous Question's.

Comment: I usually protect low-level questions that have many views. The [recently protected list](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions) should give you many examples of questions with thousands of views and few upvotes (e.g., https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301068/84967, at 11k and +1/-1 votes).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes, these are exactly the kinds of questions I'm talking about. How do you find these questions? Do you have a way of knowing if these views came steadily or in a sudden surge?

Comment: @tparker I mostly stumble upon them in the Late Answer queue, or when Community bumps them into the front page. And I have no idea where the views come from, but I always assumed it's due to google. SE is usually positioned to the top of a google search, so I guess that's where most clicks come from.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform @ tparker If finding questions with low score and high viewcounts is a goal in itself, it is [easily doable using SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/885704/questions-with-low-score-and-high-viewcounts).

Comment: Also: from some initial testing on SEDE, this *just* misses out on the 99th percentile by views, which at about 18,300 views.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I see you took that 'goal in itself' bit to heart ;-) - I'm glad to see [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74970/) got spared, at least. I've updated the query to include a views/mo field which might also be useful.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I cannot protect that one, it doesn't have any deleted/downvoted answer. I would if I could :-P

Comment: Part of the answer may be psychological: When a particular question begins to get a large number of views, others may wonder what the fuss is about and view it, increasing the number of views ….?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, search analytics are kinda crap, and we appear to have lost most of the historical data for Stack Exchange sites in Google Analytics. So I can't really give you much in the way of inside info here, other than to note that the view counter doesn't rely on any external system - [more info here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated). So while view counts aren't perfectly accurate, they're probably pretty solid over long periods of time (which is the case here).

So, let's do a bit of amateur detective work via archive.org:

- [15 days after the question was posted](https://web.archive.org/web/20130421052437/https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60119/kinetic-energy-of-alpha-particle-in-212po-decay) it had 77 views (note that this is the only period where it could've reasonably gotten into the Hot Network Questions list, and clearly it didn't)
- [7 months after being asked](https://web.archive.org/web/20141027104204/https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60119/kinetic-energy-of-alpha-particle-in-212po-decay) it had 2015 views (avg 287 views a month)
- [18 months](https://web.archive.org/web/20141027104204/http://physics.stackexchange.com:80/questions/60119/kinetic-energy-of-alpha-particle-in-212po-decay) 3919 views (avg 105 views/mo since last sample)
- [29 months](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919025149/http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60119/kinetic-energy-of-alpha-particle-in-212po-decay) 4342 views (avg 38 views/mo since last sample)
- [43 months](https://web.archive.org/web/20161225033425/http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60119/kinetic-energy-of-alpha-particle-in-212po-decay) 9681 views (avg 381 views/mo since last sample)
- [48 months](https://web.archive.org/web/20170405184054/http://physics.stackexchange.com:80/questions/60119/kinetic-energy-of-alpha-particle-in-212po-decay) 10944 views (avg 84 views/mo since last)

And today at 64 months it has 16804 views, or about 366 views/mo since the last capture on Archive.org.

This jibes pretty well with [knzhou's theory](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10753/why-do-some-random-seeming-questions-have-huge-numbers-of-views/10755#10755): regular crops of students googling for info and landing on that particular question. So I'd probably go with that as my assumption too.

To confirm, I sampled the server request logs for a few days over the past year, and all hits to that question came from... Google.

Comment: Thanks for the great detective work. Looks like you've got it, although I admit that I'm a bit mystified as to exactly what terms tens of thousands of people could be Googling to get to that particular question. Maybe we should be concerned that so many high school and undergraduate student are apparently studying polonium in such depth...

Comment: @tparker That question is [top ranked under 'alpha particle kinetic energy'](https://www.google.com/search?q=alpha+particle+kinetic+energy) on my machine - I'd wager that that's a substantial contributor to that traffic.

Comment: @tparker Because high schoolers have to calculate the kinetic energy of an alpha particle all the time. Some particular calculations gain almost mythical important in high school science because they can be performed with nothing more than a calculator, arithmetic knowledge, and a lookup table; these questions are easy to mass-produce and easy to grade. Literally 25% of the content and over 25% of the points of a unit on "nuclear physics" in a "modern physics" high school course will probably be devoted to this one calculation alone.

Comment: If one big school system uses a textbook with this question in it, that would account for many times this number of views over time.  (The system I taught in had >140k students, and they were ALL required to take Physics when they get to 11th grade -- if they didn't drop out first.)

Comment: I think the historical view count of the questions could be an useful data for tuning the sites for growth. You have the logs, maybe you could import it into some local db for data mining (if you don't do that already).

Answer (score 13):

It's not the HNQ effect; the upvote/view ratio is all wrong for that, and the views come in over too long a time period. It's just the fact that StackExchange is good at search engine optimization, and the market for high school homework help is *huge*.

The unusually popular questions have one of two features. Either they contain the exact text of a commonly assigned high school textbook problem, or they contain a common phrase, so that somebody googling "how to convert enthalpy from J/g to kJ/mol" will land on the question with title "Converting enthalpy from J/g to kJ/mol". If a question's title or body matches what the typical high school student is searching for a little bit better, it'll get 100 times the views.

Speaking as a former high school student, I'm sure you'll all agree high school science is terrible. Most things are explained poorly, and many homework questions hinge on arbitrary conventions and unstated assumptions, when they're even correct to begin with. (Last year I helped my sister through a chemistry class where she kept getting zeroes for writing "8.392 kJ/mol" instead of "8.393 kJ/mol". Apparently, not only the way you round but the *rounding convention for intermediate calculations* must match for credit.)

So it's not surprising that every day, millions of students return home and start googling for homework help. This market is what gives sites like Quora and Yahoo Answers view counts that are ~100x ours, but also their much lower quality. This is the real reason the homework policy exists.

Comment: How can one see the timing of the view count progression?

Comment: @tparker It's extremely unlikely that you'll be able to find that data - as far as I understand, via [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287827/184688) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292366) (also [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64658)), SE doesn't keep historical logs of viewcounts.

Comment: Also, please convey to your sister my sincere sympathy and reassure her that science eventually does get better once you clear the initial layer of morons. That story's appalling.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yeah, that's why I'm confused how knzhou knows that "the views come in over too long a period."

Comment: This is certainly supported by the fact that many of these questions are closed.

Comment: @tparker Because an question with less than 2 upvotes will not stay on the HNQ list for long, and even questions that stay there for days are lucky to get ~10k views typically; the traffic simply isn't enough to get the numbers we're seeing. Also, many of the questions are quickly closed, so they _can't_ get HNQ views. Another feature these questions have in common is that they tend to be several years old.

Comment: @tparker I basically told my sister chemistry was just silly like that, since my chemistry class was just the same way — all bookkeeping and arbitrary unjustified rules. But it would kill me if her physics class next year was just as bad!

Comment: An update for posterity: the physics class was even worse.

Answer (score 2):

One common answer is the Hot Network Questions sidebar that appears across the Stack Exchange network. Questions that get in the HNQ often attract views (and votes, and don't get me started on that) far out of proportion to the day to day expectations of the site.

As far as I know, being selected to appear in the HNQ sidebar does not leave a audit trail that is visible even to site moderators, so I can't say if that question did or did not partake of the HNQ effect.

Comment: Isn't there a bit of a chicken-and-egg issue though, because don't questions only become HNQs once they've already received a lot of views?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to take very many clicks or votes if they happen very shortly after the question is posted. And the list can be a bit of a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: More on the audit trail for HNQs on the mother meta: [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286986/), [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238445), and a third-party tool [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295727). More on the chicken-and-egg problem [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286020).

Comment: But wouldn't you assume the HNQ questions attract significantly ore upvotes?